# Is it possible to have homebrew update node to v0.4.2?

Tags: macos, homebrew, node.js

Atm I have homebrew installing node on my mac, when I run `brew update node` it says

> Already up-to-date.

Then when I do `node -v` I get

> v0.2.6

Is there some way to get brew to update to v0.4.2 atm? or do I need to build from source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`brew update` updates `brew` itself, as well as the formulas.

```
update Fetch the newest version of Homebrew from GitHub using git(1).
```

---

I started out today with Homebrew 0.7.1 and got the following:

```
$ brew info node
node 0.4.0
http://nodejs.org/
Not installed
```

Then I ran `brew update` and get:

```
$ brew info node
node 0.4.2
http://nodejs.org/
Not installed
```

and

```
$ sudo brew install node
==> Downloading http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.4.2
```

---

So if your `brew` is up to date, you should also have access to a current version of `node` -- try `brew install node` again.

If that doesn't help, try running `which node` to see if this is really the Homebrew `node` you're running `node -v` on.

Comment: weird `brew install node` worked..

Comment: I had homebrew 0.7.1 too..

Answer (score 0):

The current best practice for updating a specific formula (e.g. node):

`brew upgrade <formula>`

If you want to, you may issue `brew cleanup` afterwards, to get rid of leftover cruft from older versions in the Cellar.